# How to set the Page Size for an Xps Document?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, fixeddocument, documentpaginator

I am trying to save an XPS document with a [FixedDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.fixeddocument%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). So far, I have failed to change the page size. **How can I change it to a custom size?**

I have based my code on [the first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502198/convert-wpf-xaml-control-to-xps-document), more specifically, I am using this code:

```
        if (File.Exists(filename)) {
            File.Delete(filename);
        }

        var oldParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as ContentControl;
        try {
            oldParent.Content = null;

            FixedDocument doc = new FixedDocument();

            PageContent pageCnt = new PageContent();
            FixedPage page = new FixedPage();

            page.Children.Add(this);
            try {
                ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageCnt).AddChild(page);
                doc.Pages.Add(pageCnt);

                XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(filename, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                try {
                    var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc);
                    writer.Write(doc);
                }
                finally {
                    xpsDoc.Close();
                }
            }
            finally {
                page.Children.Clear();
            }
        }
        finally {
            ((ContentControl)oldParent).Content = this;
        }
```

It copies a user control into an XPS document and does so successfully, but, as I said, uses a default paper size.

I have tried to use the `DocumentPaginator.PageSize` property to set a new page size (after instantiating `FixedDocument`), but whatever I assign to that property seems to be ignored; the page in the resulting XPS document retains its default paper size.

When executing stepwise, I can see that the value of the `PageSize` property has really changed, so it's not like the new value somehow isn't accepted by the `DocumentPaginator`.

I have found various online resources, none of which has solved my problem as yet:

- [This forum posting at MS Social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/wpf/thread/d615c4b5-80fa-4eeb-808b-d79171b753e6) insists that setting the `PageSize` property works, but it does not as far as I can tell.
- [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentpaginator.pagesize%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) claim that setting the `PageSize` property works and provide an example which does the same as what I've tried. (Other than that, based on this docs page I can't even tell the unit of the numbers to use.)
- The docs also point to the [`DocumentPage.Size` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentpage.size%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), however that property cannot be publicly changed. Do I really have to override some page class before adding the page to the document just to get a different page size?
- [This forum posting](http://mindfusion.eu/Forum/YaBB.pl?board=wpfdg_disc;action=display;num=1295285990) describes the same problem, but the answer seems nonsensical to me. I am using the `DocumentPaginator` property only ever once, so there is no "calling (...).DocumentPaginator again" for which I could save an instance.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495914/fixeddocument-page-size) sounds promising, but it is actually not about the page size, but about the scale of an image on a given page.
- Aside from the aforementioned `PageSize` property (which is set to what seems to be the default size anyway here), [this tutorial](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/B_Printing.html) uses the `Width` and `Height` properties of a `FixedPage`. However, assigning some positive random values to these for a quick test would result in my XPS document apparently being corrupted and XPS Viewer displaying an error message when opening it.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

FixedDocuments have fixed pages. The height and width of FixedPage can be controlled. Somewhat like this:

```
        FixedPage pageOne = new FixedPage();
        pageOne.Height = 20;
        pageOne.Width = 10;
```

or in XAML:

Height="20" Width="10"

Answer (score 1):

I believe a FixedDocument will only print at the size of its pages. Even when loading a FixedDocument into a DocumentViewer, changing the printer settings' page size when you click the print button will have no effect. A FixedDocument by its very definition preserves the fidelity of the its contents exactly.

The only way to modify it is to create a derived DocumentPaginator which calls the FixedDocument.DocumentPaginator's functions internally and modifies the return values accordingly.